# Android custom keyboard sending images

Tags: android, keyboard

my customer wants me to write a custom keyboard that's capable of "write images". The idea is, that the keyboard will display predefined set of images and when user clicks on one of them, the keyboard inserts it to the IM conversation / mail body or whatever user is editing at the moment.

Let me clarify - my opinion is, that this isn't possible. But I need to be sure before refusing this requirement.

There are several keyboards in Google Play that put images to the text, but always in the form of HTTP links, never directly. There are others, that launch new intent when user clicks on image, so I don't consider these to be image keyboards, just image senders.

I tried to use ImageSpan to insert image to the text, but it is not honored by the application. I tried ImageSpan with drawable, but perhaps ImageSpan with image Uri may work? Did anyone achieve such functionality?

Thanks for all hints

Comment: Well, you can't force all applications to have the `INTERNET` permission, if the planned `Uri` would use `https`. And an `ImageSpan` may be lost/mangled when the contents of the `EditText` are used by the app (probably one of the reasons the other keyboards you cite use text links).

Comment: this is perhaps you can only use one of 22 `android.text.ParcelableSpan`s

Comment: The question is - are all spans sent from keyboard to the application or is the InputConnection transferring only simple unicode texts?

Comment: @CommonsWare and what if the Uri will point to a local content provider? Might this work?

Comment: "are all spans sent from keyboard to the application or is the InputConnection transferring only simple unicode texts?" -- I have no idea. "and what if the Uri will point to a local content provider?" -- at most, the image might show up in the `EditText` while the user is typing. But that will be useless, as there is no way that the image will make it to the recipient of "the IM conversation / mail body".

Comment: The same problem, so far the only way I see to use intents.

Comment: Thank you all for your thoughts. We gave up the keyboard functionality, because I'm convinced it's not possible to achieve what's requested.